# How to set multiple local variables to the same value in a single declaration?

Tags: javascript

Consider the following:

```
(function(){
   var foo = bar = 1;
}());
```

- *foo* will be a local variable to the function
- *bar* will be a global variable to the window

Due to their scoping, both variables will have a value of 1 inside the function, but *bar* will persist outside the function (in global scope).

I'm curious if there is a way to initialize variables using the *assignment operator*, **without a loop or an object**.  I'm looking for a keyword or prefix that would make *bar* locally scoped.  The idea is to be DRY and efficient.

---

Edit:
The example above is simple. One option, using 10 variables, might be to predeclare the variable to the local scope before initializing it:

```
var foo, bar, baz, foobar, foobaz, bazfoo, barbaz,
    bazbar = foo = bar = baz = foobar = foobaz = barbaz = true;
```

However, doing so is both repetitive and harder to read.  A person could use an array or object, but that is a little less clear and more cluttered.

The background was that another developer was doing `var foo = bar = true` inside a function, which I pointed out is only setting one local variable.  They were not aware of that and wanted to change and asked if it's possible to inline and set multiple local variables, without typing each one multiple times (and not refactor code w/ array or object).

Upon originally asking this question, I was exposed to ES6, but had yet to fully read the docs.  My thinking was that ES6 has some nice features (e.g., rest, destructuring assignment) and so perhaps it also provided a way to massively initialize a large block of variables to the same scope and value.

Comment: Is `var foo, bar; foo = bar = 1;` good enough?

Comment: All variables are always initialized using an assignment and a loop is not necessary. What EXACTLY is your situation as this example does not make it clear.

Comment: @JCOC611, right but that's not DRY

Comment: @ScottMarcus see the edit for clarification.  A loop would be used for arrays or object key assignments.  The comment was meant to deter those type of answers.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can't (or shouldn't) assign a value to an undeclared variable.

Then, when you want to declare multiple variable with the same value, you can

- Assign the same value to each variable:

  ```
  var var1 = value,
      var2 = value,
      /* ... */
      varN = value;
  ```

  In case `value` is an expensive expression, you can use `var1` instead of repeating `value` to avoid recalculating it each time, e.g.

  ```
  var foo = 1, bar = foo;
  ```
- Declare all variables first, and then assign the values to all of them:

  ```
  var var1, var2, /* ..., */ varN;
  var1 = var2 = /* ... = */ varN = value;
  ```

  You can do it in a single statement and avoid repeating the last variable, e.g.

  ```
  var foo, bar = foo = 1;
  ```
- If you really want to avoid repeating the variables and the values, you could try a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) with [`[].fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill):

  ```
  var [var1, /*...*/ varN] = new Array(n).fill(value);
  ```

  But I don't recommend it because it will create an useless array.

Comment: Right, the desire is to declare and initialize in one shot.  It doesn't appear doable, but good answer.

Comment: I didn't remember `.fill(...)` -- that's a clever one.

Comment: All answers are pretty clever, I'm going to select this because it offers a few alternatives, hopefully someone seeing this comment will no that what I was after isn't possible, but there's several creative attempts in this and other answers, which should all be explored.

Comment: For the variant 3, be careful that if `value` is an object, `fill()` is *not* making a shallow copy, just copying references...

Comment: for this `var foo, bar = foo = 1;`  Can anyone break it down for me? I did eg: `var foo, bar = 1;` but it just said bar was undeclared. Just curious on how this works

Answer (score 4):

It's not very nice, but here's an interesting option that's sort-of DRY:

```
(function(){
  with ({_: 1}) var x = _, y = _;
}());
```

The `with` statement creates a de-facto temporary `_` variable, which we apply only to our `var` statement to ensure there are no other side effects. This does repeat `_`, but avoids repeating anything meaningful. However, this is a terrible choice because (a) it kills the optimizer by using `with`, (b) it's not supported in strict mode due to using `with`, and (c) it relies on `var`'s scope semantics, which we're all trying to get away from by using `let` and `const` from now on.

I suppose we could use this more coherent ES6 equivalent.

```
(function(){
  { let _ = 1; var x = _, y = _; }
}());
```

However, I feel even more wrong to be taking advantage of `var` and `let`'s different semantics in the same line.

*Let*'s forget we ever had this train of thought.

---

If you want to declare two variables and initialize them using a single expression inside of a single statement, the only reasonable syntactic option the following. There is no option that avoids repeating the variable name without involving an additional variable or object.

```
(function(){
  var bar, foo = bar = 1;
}());
```

It works, but it's incompatible with the ES6 `const` keyword, because `bar` isn't being assigned by the declaration (`const bar`), but by a sub-expression (`bar = 1`). There's no supported way to accomplish this with `const` as a single statement.

```
(function(){
  const bar, foo = bar = 1;
}());
```

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration
```

The multi-line version obviously has no such issue. For what it's worth, I also find it easier to read.

```
(function(){
  const foo = 1;
  const bar = foo;
}());
```

Comment: Correct, +1 for mentioning constants, but doesn't look like JS is yet  capable of declaring and initializing multiple variables to the same value at once.

Comment: @vol7ron Yeah, it doesn't look like it. I had the same thought as guest271314 that there might be some clever possibilities around destructuring (maybe with default values, somehow?), but no dice.

Answer (score 1):

You could use destructing assignment

```
(function(){
  var [foo, bar] = [1, 1];
  console.log(foo, bar)
}());
```

Comment: While the value is still repetitive +1 for a creative approach